Magento 2.4 how to hide out of stock for one category while showing them for other categories?
I want to hide out of stock product for one category while showing them for other category. Please suggest me how to do it
I tried turning hide out of stock on but it is hiding for all category. Please suggest me any method for it

You may want to read [ask].

Create a custom module
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager:etc:config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="custom_out_of_stock_filter_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductCollectionPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>

Create a plugin file
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class ProductCollectionPlugin
{
    protected $request;
    protected $stockStatus;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        Status $stockStatus
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->stockStatus = $stockStatus;
    }

    public function beforeLoad(Collection $subject)
    {
        $categoryId = $this->request->getParam('id'); // Get the current category ID

        if ($categoryId == 'SPECIFIC_CATEGORY_ID') { // Replace with your specific category ID
            // Apply filter to hide out-of-stock products for this category
            $subject->getSelect()->join(
                ['stock_status' => $subject->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_status')],
                'e.entity_id = stock_status.product_id',
                []
            )->where('stock_status.stock_status = ?', 1);
        }

        return $subject;
    }
}

